# Makefile with symbols confusion

Tags: makefile, command

I have makefile and I'm confused about what this command does

```
build:
    mkdir -p $@

%: build/%
    cp $< $@
```

Can any body explain it?

Comment: Please edit your question to have proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The makefile defines two rules: `build` and a pattern rule.   The `build` rule simply creates a directory called `build` (note: `$@` expands to the name of the target -- see [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)).

The second rule is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html).  The pattern here is `%`, which matches anything.   That target is dependent on `build/%` where the `%` is the target name.   (so `foo` would be dependent on `build/foo` for example).   If the dependency exists or can be built, `foo` would be created by copying the first dependency (`$<` expands to the first dependency which would be `build/foo`) to `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for your complete and brief answer